# Using Zurb Foundation with Kendo UI

Tags: responsive-design, kendo-ui, zurb-foundation

I am using the latest Foundation (3.x). What's the best way to also use KendoUI and leverage the responsive features of Zurb while also getting the JS bits of Kendo (such as charting).

Does anyone have experience in this, especially with the mobile version of sites? What should I watch out for?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was also really interested to work with KendoUI and Foundation toghether, since I much prefer the last one for responsive sites, instead of Bootstrap.

So I started to check in the last couple of days if it was possible and there wasn't any design style issues between KendoUI and Foundation. Well some issues came up and here is how I fixed them:

Using Foundation 4.3.1 and KendoUI Web 2013 Q2:

1. **KendoGrid widget**: the header is too high

   - simply remove the Table class-style support in Foundation
2. **KendoDropDownList widget and similar (i.e. ComboBox, DatePicker, etc...) and Drag n'Drop in KendoGrid**: popup window too far from the literal, drag n'drop too far from the pointer

   ```
   body {
       position: static;
   }


   *[class*="k-"] {
       -moz-box-sizing: content-box !important;
       -webkit-box-sizing: content-box !important;
       box-sizing: content-box !important;
   }
   table {
       margin-bottom: 0px!important;
   }
   ```

This is the code you have to add in order to have almost everything ok for KendoUI (I hope, so far I didn't find any gliches yet). Be careful about the last code, since it's gonna apply the style to all the tags that have classes that starts with "k-" (it's a convention in KendoUI Team to put a "k-" to all the names).

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thanks for the really valuable info!

Comment: I just added the same piece of css to my project (Foundation 4) yesterday. This works quite well, but there are still issues with kendo pop-ups, for example with the editor widget when you try to add a anchor tag. The alignment is all messed up. I'm still looking for a better solution

Comment: I dropped a line to Telerik to get some support for this. I will post the solution, if one is provided offcourse :-)

Comment: Telerik just confirmed this: 'We have tweaked our stylesheets to avoid some of the major issues that Foundation Zurb inflicts. Changes will take effect in the Q3 2013 release, due in about two weeks.'

Comment: I edit your answer with more css to fix the problems with kendo popups.

Comment: Sweet! What Telerik told you is great, although I'm checking the BETA of Q3 with Foundation (4.3.2) and nothing has changed yet, we will see for the final release.

Zurb told me instead the version 5 of Foundation will be released for the end of the year! I hope with more CSS elements/components.

Comment: @Alexian allright, will see! I'm also looking forward to Foundation 5, just a couple weeks :-)

Comment: Foundation 5 is out! And so it KendoUI 2013 Q3 with responsive functionalities :) during the keynote I asked for clarifications about compatibilities between KendoUI and Zurb Foundation and they told to the audience that their is now compatible with Bootstrap, Foundation and others that I didn't catch.

Well... it's time for testing all such stuff ;)

Comment: What does Kendo UI provides that Foundation doesn't? We have been using foundation and we wan't a responsive data grid, so far we used JQgrid, which is good enough to get us by, but Kendos seem very nice, although adding this only for the grid is a bit much, hence the question. Which parts of each are you planning on using? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I think this is a little bit off-topic, however in a nutshell let's say if you really need advanced widgets for business-prjs KendoUI is a good choice (but you can choose among KendoUI, jqWidgets, Wijmo, IgniteUI, PrimeUI and others).

I don't want to go deep in the reason, but if you need more informations about it, make a proper Question :)

Answer (score 6):

1. Use Zurb 4 and the latest Kendo UI.
2. Go into Zurb's app.scss file
3. Turn off (comment out) these components: forms, custom-forms, and tables

if you find any weirdness, you can use this helper CSS as a CSS Fix, and just add the class to a DIV wrapped around your kendo widget:

```
.foundation-kendo *, .foundation-kendo *:before, .foundation-kendo *:after {
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

e.g.

```
<div class="foundation-kendo">
    <div id="grid"></div>
</div>
```

The above CSS hack should remain fairly unnecessary if you follow step 3.

Comment: Thanks. We tinkered with Zurb 3 and Kendo, and basically gave it up. From your suggestion, may I confirm that Zurb 4 will play better with Kendo UI? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You might try using Foundation 4-just released. They moved from using jQuery to Zepto, which may eliminate conflicts. Nothing wrong with Bootstrap, though.

Comment: I agree about giving it a try with foundation 4. according to the [release page](http://www.zurb.com/article/1173/foundation-4-is-here-the-smartest-foundat) you can switch out Zepto for jQuery, which you will need to do for Kendo, but they have done a lot to restrict the name space, make it more compatible, etc. I suggest trying it with just the DataViz part of Kendo if those are the feature you are looking for. Otherwise, looks like there will be some overlap if you go for the entire framework. Post back if you get it to work.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure this is the answer you want to hear...nor am I sure it is the correct answer...but here is my experience.

I have an existing project that we have been working on which uses Zurb Foundation 3.  It is an MVC4 web app and we are using VS2012.  We are really liking the responsive design stuff from Foundation...but we wanted to use a couple of the Kendo Widgets.

After getting my feet wet learning/experimenting with the widgets in a standard MVC project without Foundation, I decided to try to put Kendo into the project with Foundation.  I spent half day trying to get it to work and never could get the two working together.  If I pull the foundation stuff out, the Kendo stuff works just fine.  Rather than spend anymore time working on trying to get this working we are looking at possibly just moving to twitter bootstrap instead.

According to this blog http://www.kendoui.com/blogs/teamblog/posts/13-01-18/easy_application_layout_with_twitter_bootstrap.aspx the Kendo stuff should work well with bootrap and for our purposes bootstrap would work just as well in our app as Foundation did.

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks, but we prefer Foundation.